# What does ((uint32_t *)arg) mean? (The context is below)

Tags: c, driver

```
int alpharomeo_probe(struct tty_struct *tty, uint32_t *arg)
{

    ((uint32_t *)arg) = 0xdeadbeef;  // This line
         <more code>

}
```

Comment: In a context where an lvalue is expected, it does not mean anything, because it is not an lvalue. Are you sure that the code you are looking at is supposed to be C and that you copied it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

> 0xDEADBEEF ("dead beef") is frequently used to indicate a software
>   crash or deadlock in embedded systems. DEADBEEF was originally used to
>   mark newly allocated areas of memory that had not yet been initialized
>   -- when scanning a memory dump, it is easy to see the DEADBEEF. It is used by IBM RS/6000 systems, Mac OS on 32-bit PowerPC processors and
>   the Commodore Amiga as a magic debug value. On Sun Microsystems'
>   Solaris, it marks freed kernel memory. On OpenVMS running on Alpha
>   processors, DEAD_BEEF can be seen by pressing CTRL-T. The DEC Alpha
>   SRM console has a background process that traps memory errors,
>   identified by PS as "BeefEater waiting on 0xdeadbeef".

So take it as arg = NULL;
Anyway, I am interested to know where the code comes from.

Comment: I don't believe he was asking the meaning of DEADBEEF, rather what the (uint32 *) before the assignment was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Well in the context of that code it doesn't really mean anything. That sort of syntax would suggest that arg is being casted to a pointer to 32bit unsigned int type, however in that example it is appearing in the place of an lvalue where a cast obviously would not be relevant. So it would lead me to believe that it is a declaration from an overzealous parenthesis user, declaring a variable called arg which is a pointer to the uint32 type. However, arg is already declared. SO i would guess that the variable name was copied wrong or it is on the wrong side of the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Ans:- Points to a 4-byte location containing the argument. Second line is setting that value to deadbeef